# DynamoDB PHP Return Value

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, error-handling, return, amazon-dynamodb

I am studying how to write php code of DynamoDB now.

I have encounter some problems.

**1) How can I know when connect to db fail**

```
$aws = Aws::factory('config.php');
$client = $aws->get('DynamoDb');
```

Return client is a object, but i don't know how to check connect success or fail in my php code.

**2) Same question when i try to putItem, updateItem and deleteItem**

```
$result = $client->putItem(array(
        ...
    ));
```

I read the AWS SDK of PHP document, but I can't find solution.

These function return value is a array(?) and no attribute is mean success or fail.

Only queryItem() can check by 'Count' attribute.

**How should I do in my php code to check these ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding #1, the "connection" should not be treated the same way as a connection to a MySQL database. Requests to DynamoDB are made over HTTP(S), and this does not require that you establish an upfront connection. When you create the client object, you are not making a connection to DynamoDB, you are just configuring an HTTP client that will make requests to DynamoDB.

Regarding #2, I think you should read the [SDK's Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html), especially the sections on **Working with modeled responses** and **Detecting and handling errors**. Basically, if a request succeeds you get a `Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model` object, which behaves like an array (i.e., implements PHP's `ArrayAccess` and `Traversable` interfaces). If the request fails, an exception is thrown. For DynamoDB, that exception will be `Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException`.

```
try {
    $result = $client->putItem(array(
        'Table' => 'my-table',
        // ...
    ));
} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    // The PutItem operation failed.
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```